# Printing is cutting off the edges of my fboxes

Tags: pdf, margins, printing

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}  
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \textbf{Course:} \hfill \textbf{Essay} \rule{2em}{0.2pt} \textbf{of} \rule{2em}{0.2pt}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

The right margin of the fbox is cut off when I print the document. It looks fine in print preview, however. What can I do about this? Where is the problem? What should I try to diagnose the problem?

Looking more closely at the pdf onscreen, it seems like the left margin is still bigger than the right margin: they should be the same. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue about (La)TeX, but with your printer and its abilities to print near the border of pages. Some pdf viewers (Preview and Adobe Reader at least) will offer you an option to “scale to fit” which reduces the size of the document a bit to stay within the printer margins.

Comment: @Juan I was using evince's "shrink to fit" option, but it makes no difference. I will try a different pdf reader...

Comment: Okular does the same thing.

Comment: @Seamus: a lot of the printers need 5mm on the right and left side, there are some technical reasons that they cannot print there.

Comment: I changed the right margin to 15mm and that worked fine. Do you think I should delete this question, or keep it up for posterity? (It might not be a LaTeX question directly, but it will be a problem other TeXers will run into...)

Comment: I think this is a common problem people frequently run into, so it is worth having this question here as a reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,right=15mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
```

Fixed the problem. Too small margins mess with what the printer is capable of.